# svg rendered event after its parent div is shown

Tags: javascript, svg

Here is my html

```
<div id="parent_div" style="display:none">
    <svg width=400 height=200>elements of svg in here</svg>
</div>
<button onclick="showParentDiv();" />
```

Here is my javascript

```
function showParentDiv() 
{
    //I need a svg onload event is fired after its parent div is shown.
    //End function
    $("#parent_div").show();
}
```

Thanks for your helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SVG even for "finished rendering", but there is a "load" event as many HTML elements have.  The load event fires when the SVG has finished parsing the SVG and loaded any external references.  It should suit your needs.

If you have multiple SVGs, then you will need to keep track of when all the load events fire, and show the div when all have been received.

Below is a demo showing how the process works for one SVG element.

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var mysvg = document.getElementById("mysvg");

mysvg.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {
  
  mydiv.style.display = "block";
  
});
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none">
  
  <svg id="mysvg">
    <circle cx="75" cy="75" r="75" fill="deepskyblue"/>
    <circle cx="225" cy="75" r="75" fill="goldenrod"/>\
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to do something after .Show() is done. According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/show/), you can attach a function to the done event by doing something similar to this:

```
$( "#parent_div" ).show("slow",function() {
    // Insert code after "show" is done here
});
```

Comment: I have used it. 
But i have 12 svgs element, and after callback run, just 6 svg element is rendered.